# PHP JSON Returns \u0000

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

When I try to get data from the database via Ajax, PHP returns this:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000array(4) {\n  [\"USR_ID\"]=>\n  string(1) \"1\"\n  [\"PLT_ID\"]=>\n  string(1) \"1\"\n  [\"NRS.ID\"]=>\n  string(1) \"1\"\n  [\"url\"]=>\n  string(59) \"http://remcocr9.nine.axc.nl/tones/music/ontopoftheworld.mp3\"\n}\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php    
    class Playlist
    {
        public function getPlaylists( $link, $song, $usrid )
        {
            $playlists = $link->query( "SELECT * FROM TO_PLT WHERE USR_ID = " . $usrid . ";" );
            if( $playlists->num_rows ) // 1 or more playlists were found
            {
                while( $playlist = $playlists->fetch_assoc( ) )
                {
                    // echo an opening DIV containing the playlist name etc via json

                    $data = $song->getSong( $link, $playlist[ "PLT_ID" ], $usrid);

//                    echo json_encode($data);
                    var_dump($data);
//                    echo json_encode($playlist); // Return playlist data
                    // echo a closing DIV tag via JSON so the playlist DIV is closed
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // no playlists were found
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

And here is the javascript/ajax code that I use to get the data:

```
function ajaxRequest() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: hostURL + "users.php",
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}).fail(function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
}
```

The function is called by the Ajax function, how do I get rid of the `\u0000`? or is there another error in my code which is causing this?

Comment: Well, you are certainly not returning JSON. That's one reason why it fails.

Comment: I suppose that's a utf-8 code, maybe It's a special character or a letter with accent mark.

Comment: Don't `echo json_encode` within a loop, put all your data into an array/object and then `echo json_encode` that

Comment: I edited the code and made it store all the returned data inside the loop store inside a global array, and then outside the loop I returned that global array, but it's still returning the \u0000 :/

Comment: How do you output that array? With var_dump() or with echo json.encode()?

Comment: I use a echo to output the array

Comment: Your `$song->getSong` method is retrieving your data oddly or the stored data was stored incorrectly. I would look into the method or make sure your stored data is correctly stored

Comment: Well, this is the song class which returns the song from the database, for some reason when I var_dump the $song it automatically adds the weird symbols(\u0000) as well. http://pastebin.com/m2D0zcQd

Comment: I just find out that the headers are causing this problem but I don't know why, I tried a several things but I can't still fix it. Here are the headers:
http://pastebin.com/Qx1w6i8S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPStorm killed my code, it added a ton of NULL text after the end of my code, this was not viewable in PHPStorm, but when I opened the file in Sublime text editor it showed me the NULL text/tags..